# Thread 1: Stopped at breakpoint 1

Tags: xcode, debugging, xcode4, breakpoints

I have a problem with XCode 4.3.2, and I cannot figure out what it is. 
I have set a breakpoint, but instead that XCode stops at the line the breakpoint is set, it shows me the thread log. I am going crazy here.

So, this is the page I see in XCode when it comes to my breakpoint. It does this is several projects and tried it both with and without zombie enabled.

[image: XCode Result]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I searched google for resetting XCode, and it seems that this post helped me out:

http://www.developers-life.com/uninstallresetting-xcode.html

However, I did this in the terminal (after I closed XCode):

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode.LSSharedFileList
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

I restarted XCode, agreed to the terms and tried breakpoints again... and so far so good! :)

Comment: I was planning to reinstall Xcode, and then I found your answer! worked like a charm!

Answer (score -1):

Close Xcode then do following things in terminal.

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode.LSSharedFileList

defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

Then restart Xcode.