# Unit Test target doesn't run on Xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, ios6

I'm on the latest beta version of Xcode (Xcode 4.5 with iOS 6.0). I've got an xcode project for an iphone app and I want to add a Unit Test target on it. I've followed carefully the instructions given on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html)  but I can't run the tests. Here's the message I read in the console:

```
Failed to find SDK: '6.0'  
error: failed to attach to process ID 0
```

The target corresponding to the main application runs perfectly well on the iPhone 6.0 simulator though.

Where can I have made a mistake?

Comment: Any results on your investigations?

Comment: no success so far... still no test in my project which is a shame :(

Comment: Ok - it's running on my side now. I had exactly the same error. What I've done: (1) Clean my project (2) Build the project from the scratch. But I would not give a dim that this will help you - sorry.

Answer (score 17):

Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools => Select the one matches with SDK.

**EDIT:**

**EDIT 2: For some people, the above method works. If not, please try:**

<s>It seems that this issue was a result of switching between more than one version of SDKs, and could be solved by specifying the current SDK as the active one with a terminal command(, which requires root privilege):</s>

```
$ sudo xcode-select --switch <path-to-your-current-xcode.app>
```

Comment: Don't know why you put a strikethrough on your first answer (Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools => Select the one matches with SDK.) as that was what worked for me... The xcode-select did not fix that issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found that in order to get Xcode to attach to my unit tests, I had to use LLDB, GDB did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I returned to an earlier snapshot that I had - the only change being that the compiler was set to GDB instead of LLVM - and surprisingly enough that seems to have worked perfectly.

Not sure why LLVM isn't working though.