# Issues after installing upgraded XCode version

Tags: iphone, xcode, uistoryboard, data-loss

I installed XCode DP 4.5 recently - just to try out iOS 6.
I opened a project using it.

When I reopened using XCode 4.2.1 again, I started having storyboard [data loss issue mentioned here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2012/Jul/msg00057.html).

I don't get this issue in 4.5 DP, but then I don't want to continue with XCode 45 DP. I am not sure if its valid to build my app with it. Also, it shows me "iPhoneOS 5.0 sdk not found warning" which is the base sdk I have set within my project.

What should I do to get rid of this issue?
Is it ok to continue using 4.5 DP? 
If not, how can I safely go back to 4.2.1?
Is there any workaround in project to make, to regain my storyboard?
I also have storyboard backed up, but as soon as I import it into my project (within 4.2.1) - it complains it cannot open it. So I suspect it's due to a setting shared both by 45 DP and 4.2.1.

Please help...

Comment: Just restore the whole project from your latest backup or from your version control system.

Comment: Tried it, but still facing same issue. They really need to fix things or existing developers will be doomed.

Comment: Paul I like to ask you: is it really a taboo to talk about 4.5 that's why I get no answers? I know its under NDA, but seriously I see so many queries floating around, not surprisingly at all as iOS 6 coming up next week. I see people even upvoting their responders, but one of mine just got downvoted by a 15-year kid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405554/xcode-4-5-issue-with-iphone-simulator#comment16671969_12405554 - is there a way on SOF to punish people who abuse their high rep?

Comment: Anyone who discusses software which is under NDA risks losing their Apple developer status, which is obviously quite serious if you make a living from writing apps for iOS or OS X. The proper place to discuss Apple tools and technology which is still under NDA would be the Apple Developer Forums. I can't imagine why anyone would not respect the NDA, but it seems a lot of people don't.

Comment: I know, I had checked before and then only I posted. The question is here: does one nitpick anyone and downvote while not doing the same with others? Does SOF has uniform policy to watch over all the questions posted? Had I not found questions already I wouldn't have posted either. Why doesn't SOF remove such content at all? SOF being highly sought after place for objc questions, they should equally consider such things that can make their stand questionable. I am no moderator nor have much reps to enforce such thing, but in places like Ric/you, I would have been more just and thoughtful.

Comment: Look here - wouldn't you think this deserves a place in apple forums too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137669/xcode-4-5-corrupting-xibs

Comment: and here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404495/xcode-4-5-error-on-ios-5, and here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688720/unit-test-target-doesnt-run-on-xcode-4-5

Comment: It's up to you if you want to risk losing your developer status - if I see people talking about NDA'd stuff on SO I usually comment, in case they don't realise, but other than that it is up to the individual. I don't understand though why anyone would take this risk when there are perfectly good Apple forums where you can discuss NDA'd tools and technologies.

Comment: @NiravBhatt that 15 years old knows more than you and I could hope to learn in the next decade.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle - it would be in good spirits if you refrain to make subjective judgements like "that 15 years old knows more than you". Both of us are here to take benefit of someone's knowledge - today or tomorrow. At the same time it does not give one (even if he is star answerer) unlimited privilege to nit-pick someone and downvote-especially when points eventually lead to professional advantage. I already explained to Paul about why I was led to query about stuff under NDA, and in the process, also uncovered a flaw in the SOF ranking system that would throw a genuine questioner out.

Comment: @PaulR, fair point. Maybe I went overboard in my urgency to get it answered - also gave you my reasoning for that. But breaking NDA is again something that I would anyway pay for - that still does not justify someone punishing me on SOF in a biased manner. I am very sure someone from moderator team must have watched this discussion. Still as I see now, I don't see any downvotes for any of the NDA-bound questions I mentioned so far. Does this tell me anything about how this forum is being run?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the occasional down-vote - I get them all the time for completely inexplicable reasons. Also note that down-votes are anonymous so you shouldn't assume that the person making the comment is the same person that down-voted you (unless they explicitly say "-1" in their comment). In other words, chill.

Comment: As for -1 by someone else, he himself did not comment on my comment about downvoting, so it's him only who has downvoted me. My only problem is - I assume he being in judgemental position because of his own high reps, and I can't contest / revert his decision. Finally "no worries about -1"..well - I wouldn't argue with you on that...so chilling up :-) - -2 doesn't make much of a difference in reps personally anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the Golden Master for iOS 6 and use that for your development. As the GM version App may be compiled for distribution with it and Xcode 4.2.1 will become obsolete.

Comment: Is this something to be gotten from within xcode? How do I safely get and install it?

Comment: Latest is: I am continuing with DP, but can't get my simulator to run when I try to launch with IPhone Simulator version 5.0, 5.1 etc.

Comment: You have access to this in your development account: https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action
If you don´t have a development account then it will become available to all on the 19. september, but the user above was using DP 4.5 and thus, has a developer access.

Comment: Thanks Hannes, I have raised this with Apple but haven't heard from them as quickly as I expected, so thought to sought external help.

Answer (score 1):

By default storyboards are set to be compatible with the current release of Xcode, and one previous release. You can choose to make them compatible with even older releases by modifying the development version pop up in the storyboard's file inspector.

Comment: thanks Jon, I saw it now. Somehow that showed disabled from 4.2.1 where I shouldn't be looking actually. Any case, I am going forward with latest version though.