# Xcode 4.5 error on IOS 5

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

I installed the GM version of xcode and i started to receive this error when i try to install my app on IOS 5 . The app works fine on IOS 6. Could someone please tell me what could be the problem ? I included the libobjc.A.dylib library and i get the same .

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found:
>   _objc_setProperty_atomic_copy
>
> Referenced from:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/8BCAAF22-5857-427D-9FDA-48D369CF3DD8/FlipBookApp.app/FlipBookApp
>   Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_atomic_copy   Referenced
>   from:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/8BCAAF22-5857-427D-9FDA-48D369CF3DD8/FlipBookApp.app/FlipBookApp
>   Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

Comment: Open XCode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Components what do you see?

Comment: ios 5.1 simulator , ios 5.0 simulator, command line tools . I installed all of this .

Comment: And your project is set to deploy target 5.1?

Comment: I install it on iPhone . I have version 5.1.1.

Comment: Having the same problem (while using GData)

Comment: I also use GData. Could this be the issue ? I can't remove it since i need youtube integration in my app .

Comment: Also , it worked just fine before using the new XCode 4.5 .

Comment: Same thing for me. using Xcode < 4.5 it works on iOS5.1 and using xcode 4.5 it works on IOS6 and does not work on IOS5.1

Comment: It has something to do with @synthesize properties. But since they work fine in other projects, I guess there is a way around this using a build setting. This is only a guess and I still don't know what setting will fix it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In GData project -> Build settings -> change "iOS deployment target" to 5.1

Comment: I am not using GData or any other project but i am still having the same issue. Please help.

Answer (score 8):

The "iOS deployment target" value of your added static library must less than or equal your project's.