# What can cause a "Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_atomic" error when compiling for iOS 5.0?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm having a compiling error in IOS 5.
The error I get is:

```
wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_atomic
Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/952C640B-8310-4028-AAE5-FD308D02B005/MorethanMusic.app/MorethanMusic
Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_atomic
Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/952C640B-8310-4028-AAE5-FD308D02B005/MorethanMusic.app/MorethanMusic
Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: these are both runtime error, not compilation errors

Comment: Are you using any external libraries or xcode projects inside your project?

Comment: Set the deployment target of your main project and all subprojects to the same release.

Comment: This is possibly related to the question asked here: ["Xcode 4.5 error on IOS 5"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404495/xcode-4-5-error-on-ios-5), but the errors are slightly different.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Paul's answer is only halfway there. After some searching, I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/gdata-objectivec-client/L0VC3Db2ZOc) thread, which suggested you make the deployment target the same for all subprojects:

[image: main project]

[image: subproject]

It doesn't matter what they are (at least for this problem), as long as they're the same.
This solved this precise error for me.

Don't forget to clean the GData Project's DerivedData Folder before building.

Comment: You just made my day sir! :)

Comment: My app crashed at launch because of subproject having higher deployment target. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Set your Deployment target to iOS5 in your build settings.

[image]