# Hello World with Cordova 3.4.1 and Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm quite new to Xcode, and I struggled the whole day to get the Hello World working.

The Cordova 'Hello World' is displaying fine through a simulator. But I can't make it work with an iPhone 4S under iOS 5.0. It hangs on the cordova logo.
I updated the target and the project to 5.0, removed arm 64 support, but still I get an error of "symbol not found".

```
dyld'dyld_fatal_error:
0x2fe01080: trap          Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)
```

-

```
dyld: Symbol not found; _objc_setProperty_nonatomic_copy
```

I configured the development account, and attached the physical device to this account..

I now feel desperate not to have any clues to understand what's going on... And also that I spent 99$ for nothing...

Comment: Were you getting 'symbol not found' prior to changing the project settings? BTW, 'symbol not found' is *not* enough information. Need more details on the error message.

Comment: Right. I edited the question with the detailed error. Prior to changing settings, I couldn't run the project as a iOS 5.0 device was not compatible.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861345/what-can-cause-a-symbol-not-found-objc-setproperty-atomic-error-when-compili help?

Comment: Thanks, I had read and tried this one. Both the main project and the Cordova sub-projet are targeting a 5.0 deployment target...

Comment: It's not 100% clear -- is the simulator iOS version also 5.0?

Comment: No, I used the default simulator ; I guess it's a 7.1, and it's working. I'm currently downloading the 6.1 simulator. And I just discovered a workaround to get back the 5.0 simulator. Thus, I hope to understand if my problem is related to the difference of iOS version, or to the simulator vs. physical device.

Comment: Well, I finally made it by upgrading the physical device to the latest (7.1) version. I just hope that the end-users will do the same...

Comment: So there must be something about 5.0 that it doesn't like. I'm not sure how much that hurts -- iOS 5 isn't that large of a percentage anymore (last I knew), though this does vary by region. Personally, I target iOS 6 and higher (and in some of my apps, only 7 and higher).