# XCode 4.5.2: How to reconcile "Failed to attach to process ID 0" with the need for a Resources folder?

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle

So, I have an iOS project in XCode 4.5.2 which is constantly throwing up the "Failed to attach to process ID 0" error when I try to run it in the Simulator, as described in this thread:

[Failed to Attach to Process ID Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535844/failed-to-attach-to-process-id-xcode)

I've tried every fix suggested there, and the only one that works is to rename the Resources folder that I have in the project to something else (e.g. "Assets"). Which would be fine, and I could move on with my life, except that doing so means that all the resources get copied into the bundle under the Assets directory. Which means that (for example) the filenames for the icons in Info.plist, and any calls to [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource ... ] also need to have "Assets/" prepended to them.

I need one of two things:

A - A suggestion about how to fixed the "Failed to attach to process" issue that doesn't involve renaming my Resources folder

B - Failing that, a way to rename the Resources folder, but have the files in that folder copied into the bundle in a way that doesn't require the folder name to be put before every single asset I want to access.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I came into this after also failing to solve my issue with the previous marked thread. The only thing that solved it for me was rebooting my mac.