# Error in xcode application: Couldn't register with the bootstrap server

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

My application crashed and showing following error for iPhone 4 but working for iphone 5 correctly

```
Couldn't register us.xxxxxx.myproject with the bootstrap server. 
Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already 
running or is hung in the debugger.(lldb)
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Already answered here… http://stackoverflow.com/a/788286/1042240

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375442/couldnt-register-with-the-bootstrap-server

Comment: Kill the other instance?

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020164/finished-running-app-on-iphone-6-1-simulator/15020367#15020367

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the app,
2. Restart the Xcode,
3. Clean and build the app,
4. Didn't do anything.

   I shut the phone down and bought it back up and the error went away.