# LLDB Makes Xcode 5.1 Crash on Project Run

Tags: xcode, macos, crash, lldb

I've only started using Xcode from this morning, although I have it for a while now. Anyway, for working mostly on C projects I used Netbeans...

To make a long story short, I noticed this morning, right after creating my first project, an OS X C Command Line Application, that when running (`CMD` + `R`) my project, Xcode crashes right after building it. It crashes exactly when it's running the project.

It doesn't give any error message, the program just quits. As I am new to Xcode, I have no idea where to find an error log file, I don't even know if there is one. Although if there is one, I would like very much to know where to find it. Searching on google didn't help me at all to locate this file.

First I thought this issue was addressed only to OS X C Command Line Application project. As a result, I tested with several other project types and I've got the same output.

Anyway, **I've managed to work around this problem by selecting no debugger** for my project in Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run  -> Info tab:
[image]

However, my projects run now, **I still need a debugger**, therefore this is not a fix for me.

I have also tried uninstalling and installing back Xcode, but the problem didn't disappear.

**Is this a common problem or is it only me?** I've seen other people complaining about problems related to mine in previous versions of Xcode, but most have found a valid solution for them that I tried as well but with no luck.

**Does anyone know how to fix this issue?** I am pretty desperate and the only 'solution' left in my mind is to see if reinstalling the OS will help me, which I would rather not do.

I forgot to mention, I am running the latest version of OS X (10.9.2) on a MacBook Pro Retina 2013 machine. Also, I've got the latest version of Xcode, 5.1 (5B130a).

**EDIT**

After creating a new user and doing the steps above I managed to get an error message from Xcode:

```
Process:         Xcode [3307]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.1 (5084)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-5084000000000000~21
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 444172641
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [3106]
Responsible:     Xcode [3307]
User ID:         502

Date/Time:       2014-04-10 19:02:19.685 +0300
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.2 (13C64)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  B87A6F4C-ADAC-0A40-43D5-CB68FB46397E

Sleep/Wake UUID: 87996F32-190A-4A5F-8E94-BE0F0E902624

Crashed Thread:  10  Dispatch queue: DBGLLDBLauncher Serial Queue

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5B130a
Assertion failed: (out_port != 0), function StartDebugserverProcess, file /SourceCache/lldb/lldb-310.2.36/source/Plugins/Process/gdb-remote/GDBRemoteCommunication.cpp, line 720.


Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89376a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89375d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93f28155 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93f27779 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93f270b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff920a4a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff920a47b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff920a45bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8968c3de _DPSNextEvent + 1434
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8968ba2b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
10  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010b50ae31 -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 84
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8967fb2c -[NSApplication run] + 553
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8966a913 NSApplicationMain + 940
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff9237c5fd start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937ae6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900bbf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937b662 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90bd143d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90bd1152 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 3:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89376a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89375d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93f28155 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93f27779 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93f270b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff890cc967 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 348
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff890cc76b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba899 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba72a _pthread_start + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89376a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89375d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93f28155 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93f27779 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93f270b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x0000000113d9540e -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 162
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff890cc76b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba899 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba72a _pthread_start + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937a9aa __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93f73b83 __CFSocketManager + 867
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba899 _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba72a _pthread_start + 137
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89376a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89375d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93f28155 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93f27779 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93f270b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8982c16e _NSEventThread + 144
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba899 _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba72a _pthread_start + 137
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89376a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89375d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93f28155 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93f27779 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93f270b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff890ceadc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 253
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff891b74aa -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74
7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation  0x0000000117506e0d -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 134
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff890cc76b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba899 _pthread_body + 138
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba72a _pthread_start + 137
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:: CVDisplayLink
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937a716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900bcc3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff9005fa38 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 656
3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff9005f78f startIOThread(void*) + 147
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba899 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba72a _pthread_start + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937ae6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900bbf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: DBGLLDBLauncher Serial Queue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937a866 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900bb35c pthread_kill + 92
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff915d6b1a abort + 125
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff915a09bf __assert_rtn + 321
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119b1c4d2 GDBRemoteCommunication::StartDebugserverProcess(char const*, unsigned short, lldb_private::ProcessLaunchInfo&, unsigned short&) + 1738
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119b232ba ProcessGDBRemote::LaunchAndConnectToDebugserver(lldb_private::ProcessInfo const&) + 216
6   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119b23824 ProcessGDBRemote::DoAttachToProcessWithID(unsigned long long, lldb_private::ProcessAttachInfo const&) + 126
7   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119bac94b lldb_private::Process::Attach(lldb_private::ProcessAttachInfo&) + 1541
8   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119bf4940 PlatformDarwin::Attach(lldb_private::ProcessAttachInfo&, lldb_private::Debugger&, lldb_private::Target*, lldb_private::Listener&, lldb_private::Error&) + 456
9   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119ba2ec7 lldb_private::Platform::DebugProcess(lldb_private::ProcessLaunchInfo&, lldb_private::Debugger&, lldb_private::Target*, lldb_private::Listener&, lldb_private::Error&) + 213
10  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119bf4724 PlatformDarwin::DebugProcess(lldb_private::ProcessLaunchInfo&, lldb_private::Debugger&, lldb_private::Target*, lldb_private::Listener&, lldb_private::Error&) + 50
11  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119bc5869 lldb_private::Target::Launch(lldb_private::Listener&, lldb_private::ProcessLaunchInfo&) + 483
12  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001188febb4 lldb::SBTarget::Launch(lldb::SBLaunchInfo&, lldb::SBError&) + 502
13  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x00000001155ce4d1 -[DBGLLDBLauncher _doRegularDebugWithTarget:usingDebugServer:errTargetString:] + 3242
14  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x00000001155d01ad __24-[DBGLLDBLauncher start]_block_invoke + 4672
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90bd21d7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90bcf2ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90bd168f _dispatch_queue_drain + 451
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90bd29dd _dispatch_queue_invoke + 110
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90bd0fa3 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 75
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90bd2193 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900bbef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937a716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900bcc77 _pthread_cond_wait + 787
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8909d930 -[NSCondition waitUntilDate:] + 344
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff890947d8 -[NSConditionLock lockWhenCondition:beforeDate:] + 232
4   com.apple.CSServiceClient       0x000000010da15558 -[CSLogger loggerThread:] + 241
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff890cc76b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba899 _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba72a _pthread_start + 137
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937ae6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900bbf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937ae6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900bbf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937ae6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900bbf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937ae6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900bbf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937ae6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900bbf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937ae6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900bbf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937ae6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900bbf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937ae6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900bbf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937a716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900bcc3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011295d363 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 524
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff890cc76b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba899 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba72a _pthread_start + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937a716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900bcc3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011295d363 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 524
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff890cc76b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba899 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba72a _pthread_start + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 22:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937a716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900bcc3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011295d363 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 524
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff890cc76b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba899 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba72a _pthread_start + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 23:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937a716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900bcc3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011295d363 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 524
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff890cc76b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba899 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba72a _pthread_start + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 24:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937a716 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900bcc3b _pthread_cond_wait + 727
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x000000011295d363 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 524
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff890cc76b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba899 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba72a _pthread_start + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 25:: <lldb.comm.debugger.input>
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937a9aa __select + 10
1   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119a315f0 lldb_private::ConnectionFileDescriptor::BytesAvailable(unsigned int, lldb_private::Error*) + 888
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119a31052 lldb_private::ConnectionFileDescriptor::Read(void*, unsigned long, unsigned int, lldb::ConnectionStatus&, lldb_private::Error*) + 170
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119a2f493 lldb_private::Communication::ReadFromConnection(void*, unsigned long, unsigned int, lldb::ConnectionStatus&, lldb_private::Error*) + 97
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119a2f0f1 lldb_private::Communication::ReadThread(void*) + 147
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba899 _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba72a _pthread_start + 137
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 26:: <lldb.comm.xcode.lldb.comm>
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937a9aa __select + 10
1   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119a315f0 lldb_private::ConnectionFileDescriptor::BytesAvailable(unsigned int, lldb_private::Error*) + 888
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119a31052 lldb_private::ConnectionFileDescriptor::Read(void*, unsigned long, unsigned int, lldb::ConnectionStatus&, lldb_private::Error*) + 170
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119a2f493 lldb_private::Communication::ReadFromConnection(void*, unsigned long, unsigned int, lldb::ConnectionStatus&, lldb_private::Error*) + 97
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119a2f0f1 lldb_private::Communication::ReadThread(void*) + 147
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba899 _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba72a _pthread_start + 137
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 27:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89376a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89375d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93f28155 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93f27779 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93f270b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff93fdc811 CFRunLoopRun + 97
6   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff94c437e3 SpotlightQueryThread(void*) + 355
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba899 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba72a _pthread_start + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 28:: listen://localhost:0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8937b64a kevent + 10
1   libsystem_info.dylib            0x00007fff8a813d3b _mdns_search + 1184
2   libsystem_info.dylib            0x00007fff8a81a75c mdns_addrinfo + 513
3   libsystem_info.dylib            0x00007fff8a81a52b search_addrinfo + 183
4   libsystem_info.dylib            0x00007fff8a81a2c0 si_addrinfo + 1468
5   libsystem_info.dylib            0x00007fff8a819c5f getaddrinfo + 171
6   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119c4edf0 lldb_private::SocketAddress::getaddrinfo(char const*, char const*, int, int, int, int) + 76
7   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119a301dd lldb_private::ConnectionFileDescriptor::SocketListen(char const*, lldb_private::Error*) + 521
8   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119a2fc39 lldb_private::ConnectionFileDescriptor::Connect(char const*, lldb_private::Error*) + 149
9   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000119b1bdd1 GDBRemoteCommunication::ListenThread(void*) + 71
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba899 _pthread_body + 138
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900ba72a _pthread_start + 137
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900befc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 10 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x000000011b0c7000  rcx: 0x000000011b0c48b8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000003f5b  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x000000011b0c48e0  rsp: 0x000000011b0c48b8
   r8: 0x00007fc91a83ae00   r9: 0x0000000000000227  r10: 0x000000000c000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x0000000119e6e0f2  r13: 0x0000000119e6e0da  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x0000000119e6dec0
  rip: 0x00007fff8937a866  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x000000010dc4b000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x020000b8
Trap Number:     133
```

Comment: Just out of the air. Are all command line tools installed?

Comment: @Hoshts As I know, from OS X 10.9 onwards Command Line Tools get installed with Xcode. Anyway to be sure, I've checked `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/` and I have all of them.

Comment: Might be true. But by the look of the error message it's a problem with the assignment of port to the gdb server that need to run for it to start. I found this change to the tool http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=198963 so there is some problem. What version of dev tools do you have installed? `xcode-select -v`

Comment: The dev tools version is `xcode-select version 2333.`. Anyway I didn't really understood what to do with http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=198963. Where can I apply that?

Comment: Same version for me. The link itself was just a reference of a change in the source files of the debugger. But it looks like it's broken on your computer. Btw, I guess you tried as root instead of your user?

Comment: Of course, that was the first thing that came in mind. Changed to root, but no success. I also reported this to Apple. Anyway, you have the same version of Xcode and this doesn't happen to you, right?

Comment: Same version of both lldb and dev tools - and no error. Well at least when I tried with a single view ios app.

Comment: By any chance, did you install brew?

Comment: With brew I guess you talking about Homebrew. I've had that for a very long time.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to that. It's obvious that something I installed is causing this. I am trying to eliminate programs to see what causes this issue. Also hoping that a OS reinstallation would solve this.

Comment: The only way I see that any brew installation would cause this is if you installed any of the compilers already in the dev tools and got things messed up that way. But hey, I'm sorry I can't be of much help. Good luck with it and I hope you find out (or last resort - reinstall).

Comment: The thing is that I actually installed a compiler in brew that was already installed. I wanted to install Octave command line, thus I followed this tutorial: http://www.computersnyou.com/2690/2014/01/install-gnu-octave-macosx-step-step/. It seemed strange for me the need to install gcc49. Anyway, it was the first thing I uninstalled, when I noticed this issued, but with no positive result. Is there any way to check if those things (from the link) installed were uninstalled completely, when I uninstalled bee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this wasn't a common issue, it was only affecting me.

They only way I managed to make Xcode work as supposed was to delete the app and reinstall the whole OS.

**UPDATE**

The bug appeared again shortly after I installed Xcode again. Therefore, I opted for a full reinstall of the OS (format the hard drive as well).

Nevertheless, after a few weeks the bug appeared again. Anyway, this time I noticed why this is occurring. The reason for that is something related with MAMP PRO MySQL port. Only if I have MAMP PRO MySQL server running, Xcode works.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and fixed it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14414016/968427.
Check the /etc/hosts file and ensure the host(127.0.0.1 localhost) is exists.