# Xcode 7.3 error: could not attach to pid:"983"

Tags: ios, xcode7.3

When I build and run on a simulator in Xcode 7.3. I get the error could not attach to pid:"983":

[image]

Some times I'm getting this error. After trying to run 2 to 3 times it works properly. Anyone help me why I am getting this error?

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535844/failed-to-attach-to-process-id-xcode

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I met the same problem yesterday and solved it.

1. clean the project (command+shift+k)
2. restart simulator if you use it
3. re-build
4. run it again.

I hope it works also for you.