# Could not attach to pid : 8335

Tags: ios, xcode7.3

I'm working on custom keyboard and when I run my project in the physical device I got this alert message

[image]

I'm using the Xcode 7.3 and iOS version in the device is 9.3.5 and my deployment target in the project is 9.0. I tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it but it not worked. Because of this, my custom keyboard is not working in the device. How can I solve this?

Comment: please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129515/xcode-7-3-error-could-not-attach-to-pid983

Comment: Hi @AmitSrivastava i already see that issue but I'm got this issue while running in device and it working perfectly in my simulator.

Comment: Choosing the right provisioning profile

Comment: one min after launched the app this dialogue is come or before????\

Comment: I already checked it. And my project is worked perfectly yesterday.

Comment: you have already set this app Trust in Device management.

Comment: I'm having this dialogue when  my custom keyboard is attaching

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126296/discussion-between-ramakrishna-and-amit-srivastava).