# Could not attach to pid : “####” unable to attach

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, xcode7.3

I just updated to Xcode 7.3.1 and my project crashes with the same error after the launch screen displays on the iOS simulator.

The error is:

> "Could not attach to pid : “1712” unable to attach"

Then I tried running another project and I got:

> "Could not attach to pid : “2025” unable to attach"

Any solutions?

Comment: did you try clean, rebuild, restart?

Comment: Wish any of the below answers would work for me :(

Comment: None of the answers on this page worked for me. I found a solution involving attaching to the process already running in the simulator. This page no longer allows answers, so I am putting the details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59304312/384670

Comment: I had the problem because of slow internet connection

Comment: De-Selecting Debug Executable option under edit scheme fixed it for me!

Answer (score 37):

Resetting the content and settings in the simulator worked for me. This is available on the iOS Simulator: Hardware -> Erase all Content and Settings

Comment: in most of the cases, this is actually the correct answer.

Comment: The menu item is now called _Hardware -> Erase All Content And Settings_.

Comment: The menu item is now called Device -> Erase All Content And Settings

Answer (score 23):

Kill the simulator, then re-build.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to kill the simulator, re-building make it work for me.

Comment: I usually just re-**run** it. But re-**building** is what's intended here.

Comment: None of these worked for me. killing the simulator, deleting the app, switching simulator, rebuilding, deleting derived data, cleaning build folder, cleaning project, none worked.

Answer (score 18):

1. I closed Xcode.
2. On the simulator menu: go to Hardware -> Erase all content and settings.
   [image: Erase all content and settings]
3. Open Xcode then build and run the application.

The above simple steps worked for me.

Comment: The order of the steps as shown here solved it for me.

Answer (score 10):

1. Close Xcode & simulator
2. Reopen Xcode & rebuild

Above steps worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

In my case Xcode 8.0 after this error,just **rebuild** again project it solves this problem.

There is no need for reset app content in iPhone device.

Answer (score -1):

Clean the project,quit the simulator and then rebuild the app

Comment: Cleaning the project and then running always make the trick for me.