# Could not attach to pid : “7722”

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, imessage, imessage-extension

I am working on `Sticker pack application`. I add some custom stickers in Sticker pack. When I tried to run the application on simulator it always says:-

> Could not attach to pid : “7722”

[image]

Comment: Did you try closing the simulator and run again ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not attach to pid : “####” unable to attach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582096/could-not-attach-to-pid-unable-to-attach)

Comment: @TejaNandamuri, Yes I did. Now error is different(pid: 8747). I think message extension app is not working perfectly with simulator. I will test it on device.

Comment: @NobodyNada, I checked that but that question is not related to imessage extension. However I reset/kill the simulator, it doesn't works.

Comment: @pkc456 I don't think it has anything to do with being an iMessage extension; that error means the debugger was unable to connect to the app.  Have you tried choosing "Reset Content and Settings" from the Simulator menu, and have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: Does your extension launch successfully after this message?

Comment: @AndreyKuznetsov, No, it is not launching successfully. In the iMessage app, only app logo is visible. No stickers are visible.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got multiple bundle identifiers.
com.tutsplus.BasicStickerPack.StickerPackExtension
and
com.programmingcrew.funsticker.StickerPackExtension

Check your project/target settings and make sure the bundle identifiers are set correctly.